# Fancybox breaks after databind

Tags: c#, jquery, database, fancybox

Something really strange is happening, Fancybox is working perfectly until I put a repeater around it.

My HTML that is working:

```
    <ul id="tiles">
      <li>
        <a href="SampleImageEnlarge" class="fancybox" title="description">
        <img src="SampleImageThumb" border="0" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The repeater that is breaking Fancybox:

```
<ul id="tiles">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptGalleryImages" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href="/ImageHandler.ashx?fId=<%# Eval("ImageID") %>&w=700" class="fancybox" title="<%# Eval("Description") %>">
                <img src="/ImageHandler.ashx?fId=<%# Eval("ImageID") %>&w=200" border="0">
                </a>
            </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
      </ul>
```

Code behind:

```
private void GetGalleryImages()
{
   using(RRLDB db = new RRLDB())
   {
       var gallery = db.Galleries.Find(_galleryId);

        rptGalleryImages.DataSource = gallery.GalleryImages.Where(x => !x.Cancelled).OrderBy(p => p.OrderField).ToList();
        rptGalleryImages.DataBind();
   }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});

$(window).load(function () {
        $("#main #tiles img").each(function () {
             $(this).attr('height', $(this).outerHeight());
        });
});
```

Anyone have an idea as to why this might be happening? Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: can you provide your jquery that fires off the fancybox

Comment: Sure, question has been edited. Thanks

Comment: http://fancybox.net/faq ==> No. 6

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks a lot.